# Using PersistGate on my React App doesn't render

Tags: reactjs, redux

I implemented a PersistGate in my application but now my App is not rendering. If I remove the PersistGate then it works fine.

store.js

```
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux'
import rootReducer from './root-reducer'
import { persistStore } from 'redux-persist'
import logger from 'redux-logger'

const middleWares = []

if(process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development')
    middleWares.push(logger)

export const store = createStore(rootReducer, undefined, applyMiddleware(...middleWares))

export const persistor = persistStore(store)
```

index.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import reportWebVitals from './reportWebVitals';
import { BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom'
import { Provider } from 'react-redux'
import { store, persistor } from './redux/store'
import { PersistGate } from 'redux-persist/integration/react'

ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <Provider store={store}>
      <BrowserRouter>
        <PersistGate persistor={persistor}>
          <App /> 
        </PersistGate>
      </BrowserRouter>
    </Provider>
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

And my App.js

```
import { GlobalStyle } from './global.styles'
import { Switch, Route } from 'react-router-dom'
import LoginPage from './pages/login/login.component'
import MainPage from './pages/main/main.component'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import { createStructuredSelector } from 'reselect'
import { selectCurrentUser } from './redux/user/user.selector'

const App = ({ currentUser }) => {
  console.log(currentUser)
  return (
    <div>
      <GlobalStyle />
      <Switch>
        <Route exact path='/' component={ LoginPage } />
        <Route exact path='/main' component={ MainPage } />
      </Switch>
    </div>
  )
}

const mapStateToProps = createStructuredSelector({
  currentUser: selectCurrentUser
})

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(App)
```

I'm not sure if the problem is the order in which I put the PersistorGate tag in my `index.js`. I did try to play around with the order but I had no success unless I removed the PersistorGate from it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you dont have a persistConfig, add this to your store.js:

```
const persistConfig = {
  key: 'root',
  storage,
};
```

You then need to create a persistedReducer with:

```
const persistedReducer = persistReducer(persistConfig, rootReducer);
```

Once you have the persistedReducer, you add that to the store instead of the rootReducer:

```
const store = createStore(persistedReducer, applyMiddleware(...middleWares));
```

more info [here](https://github.com/rt2zz/redux-persist#basic-usage)